# I have a popup div with more than one span element how to display another span

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, html

I have a popup div with more than one span element how to display another span

**javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".levert").click(function () {
$("#popUpDiv").show("slow");
});

});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="popUpDiv" style="display:none">
<img src="logo_klein.png" width="117" height="33" class="logoklein1" ><p
id="headertextbox">is</p></img>

<span class="textbox1"></span>
<span class="textbox2"></span>
<span class="textbox3"></span>
</div>
</div>
```

**Imagemap with links**

```
<img id="logo" src="./logo.png" alt="Phlox" usemap="#links"></img>


<map name="links">
<area shape="circle" coords="291,46,46" href="#" class="levert"></area>
<area shape="circle" coords="55,245,46" href="#" class="is"></area>
</map>
```

Comment: Doesn't it show already when the `#popUpDiv` is shown? If not, the answer depends entirely on *why* it doesn't show. (It really should, with the code you're showing here.)

Comment: yeah the spans are showing but the popupdiv is needed on other places with different text, so it has to be cleared and filled with another span when closed

Comment: really not providing much detail about how you want the spans managed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this when you want to clear `popupDiv` and add span with class `textbox2`

```
$("#popUpDiv").empty().append('.textbox2').show("slow");
```

Comment: will only work once this way. After the empty on second use.. `.textbox2` will no longer exist